# Where do I see the keyboard shortcuts for applications?

Tags: applications, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I see and edit keyboard shortcuts for applications like Audience, Noise and Marlin? I looked for it on system settings, keyboard. It isn't in the ui, I couldn't find manual pages for these applications, and there isn't configuration files in my home folder.

Answer (score 2):

In the keyboard settings , And Also you can set up your own shortcut in custom .

[image: Keyboard Settings]

Comment: These are for launching the applications. I mean the applications shortcuts like save, previous and next, etc.

Comment: i think each application has it's own shortcuts and you can modify it from the application itself